# Reference Table Cell's Value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table populated with a set number of TextBoxFor inputs from the page's C# Model.  Each column of these inputs has a distinct class name.  Using a .change event on any one of the classes, the changed cell's row and cell/column number are used to identify the cell in the row directly beneath it.  The value of the changed cell, however, is always showing up as undefined.  I've tried searching SO for answers, .val(), .html(), .text(), getting the changed cell's ID and applying .val() to that, but any reference to the changed cell is undefined.  How does one properly address the changed cell?  Many thanks in advance!

jQuery:

```
$('.firstClass, .secondClass, .thirdClass, .fourthClass, .fifthClass').change(function () {
     var $changedCell = $(this);
     var $changedRow = $changedCell.parent().index();
     var $cellIndex = $changedCell.index();
     var $nextRow = $changedRow + 1;
     var $table = $('#dt_myTable tr');
     var $beneathCell = $table.eq($nextRow).find('td').eq($cellIndex);
     var $changedValue = Number($changedCell.val());//Zero or Undefined, depending on using .val() or .html()/.text()!
     $beneathCell.text($changedValue);
});
```

Here's a sample of the table:

```
<table id="dt_myTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="text-center">Suggested</th><th class="text-center">First</th><th class="text-center">Second</th><th class="text-center">Third</th><th class="text-center">Fourth</th><th class="text-center">Fifth</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Primary</td>
            <td class="firstClass" align="center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstPrimary, new { @class = "form-control", data_parsley_required = "true" })</td>
            <td class="secondClass" align="center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecondPrimary, new { @class = "form-control", data_parsley_required = "true" })</td>
            <td class="thirdClass" align="center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ThirdPrimary, new { @class = "form-control", data_parsley_required = "true" })</td>
            <td class="fourthClass" align="center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FourthPrimary, new { @class = "form-control", data_parsley_required = "true" })</td>
            <td class="fifthClass" align="center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FifthPrimary, new { @class = "form-control", data_parsley_required = "true" })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><b>Result</b></td>
            <td class="firstClass" align="center"></td>
            <td class="secondClass" align="center"></td>
            <td class="thirdClass" align="center"></td>
            <td class="fourthClass" align="center"></td>
            <td class="fifthClass" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Show an example of your html.

Comment: Added for the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  That's strange, because it does seem to get the index of the cell.  If test data is put into the $beneathCell.text("Test") and the undefined line is commented out, then it updates properly.  It seems to be just accessing the changed cell and its value that doesn't work.  Yes, though, the purpose is to get the value of the changed cell and update the cell directly beneath it with the same value.

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p04w2eze/2/) - it will update the corresponding cell in the following row although its a bit unclear what the purpose of this is.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the fiddle and the simplification, but the problem is that the Number($(this).val()) line in the fiddle results in 0 when I enter a number.  If the other methods in the post are used, then the result is NaN.  Is there an obvious reason why referencing the changed cell isn't returning the value?

Comment: What?? Enter a valid number in the fiddle and it works. But this is all very strange - why are you converting to a number anyway if you just want to duplicate the value in the following row

Comment: I'm going to eventually add some numbers to it, but want to get this fixed first.  The original question is why would the line return 0 with .val(), or NaN with the other mentioned methods, that's basically the same as the one I referenced in the fiddle: var $changedValue = Number($changedCell.val());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137595/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jle).

Answer (score 0):

you trying catch cell change but you sould catch textbox change.

try something like this.

```
$('.firstClass input, .secondClass input, .thirdClass input, .fourthClass input, .fifthClass input').change(function () {
 var $changedInput = $(this);
 var $changedCell = $changedInput.parent();
 var $changedRow = $changedCell.parent().index();
 var $cellIndex = $changedCell.index();
 var $nextRow = $changedRow + 1;
 var $table = $('#dt_myTable tr');
 var $beneathCell = $table.eq($nextRow).find('td').eq($cellIndex);
 var $changedValue = Number($changedInput.val());//Undefined!
 $beneathCell.text($changedValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I tried adding the input to the class, and the value was 0 instead of the 100 I entered.  I think the issue here is that the changed cells are TextBoxFor instead of TextBox, but I want to make this code short and dynamic instead of having to reference each TextBoxFor id.

Comment: I just added an example from the table.  The rest of the table is more of the same, except substitute "Primary" for "Secondary", "Tertiary", etc.